# At what point is 'TokenManager.StoreNewRequestToken' called in the OAuth 2.0 DNOA version

Tags: facebook, dotnetopenauth, facebook-access-token

The point is, I have an app (I feel like half SO knows this already) that read info from Twitter (OAuth 1.0a) and Facebook (OAuth 2.0 'ish).

In the Twitter version I use the old WebConsumer class. It has a PrepareRequestUserAuthentication function that also calls the ITokenManager.StoreNewRequestToken function which stores the Tokens.

My question is how does this work in the WebserverClient, it has functions that all look similar, but don't seem to act in the same way.

```
            if (Application is FacebookApplication)
        {  // We need WebServerClient instead of WebConsumer so we can use OAuth 2.0
            client = new FacebookClient(this)
            {
                ClientIdentifier = Application.ConsumerKey,
                ClientSecret = Application.ConsumerSecret,
            };
            IAuthorizationState authorization = client.ProcessUserAuthorization();
            if (authorization == null)
            {
                client.RequestUserAuthorization(null, null, callback);
            }
        }
        else
        {   // Here we do need WebConsumer
            WebConsumer consumer = Application.GetConsumer(this) as WebConsumer;
            UserAuthorizationRequest authorizationRequest = consumer.PrepareRequestUserAuthorization(callback, requestParameters, redirectParameters);
            consumer.Channel.Send(authorizationRequest);
        }
```

at the moment I have a FacebookApplication Class and a TwitterApplication class. Both Inherit from OAuthWebApplication which contains has the function GetConsumer(IConsumerTokenManager tm) to return the WebConsumer for the OAuth 1.0 process. I reckon I need to add in OAuth 2.0's `WebServerClient` as well for the OAuth 2.0 process?

Comment: by the way, I am using DNOA 3.5 CTP so it should be able to communicate with Facebook. I also already looked at the sample that comes with it, and it works. But it seems I am missing something here. 

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never, since the OAuth 2 client classes in DotNetOpenAuth don't even take a token manager.

OAuth 1 requires a token manager because the client must track the intermediate state of requesting access and receiving access.  But in OAuth 2 the client is simpler because there is no request token to store -- only the final access token.

Comment: What about this code in FacebookClient.cs then?
    public FacebookClient() : base(FacebookDescription) {
   this.AuthorizationTracker = new TokenManager();
  }

Can I just ignore it?

Comment: Very interesting.  That's optional so yes I think you can ignore it.  But that's not a TokenManager at all.  That class implements `IClientAuthorizationTracker` which is quite different.  It looks like you found a poorly named class in the ApplicationBlock.  I'll get that fixed.  Thanks.

Comment: yeah that's indeed part of what flabbergasted me, since the project I am trying to integrate this in already has a tokenmanager and I wanted to use that one.